# Generate gradient css / svg backgrounds

Tags: javascript, css, svg

A few months ago I found CSS / SVG(?) generator for backgrounds like this one:

http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/bridge11/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/slide-01.jpg

Has anyone ready-made solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i finally found solution on github:

http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/